# Black title bar on fragments only

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have added the code

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Title br is now removed on my login activity but once logged in I am getting a black space between my fragment and actionbar.

[image]

What is generating this? The fragment itself?

Regards
John

Theme.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
            parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:height">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffffff</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
       <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
       <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
       <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    </style>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomFonts">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Actionbar.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Home"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/iconhome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_Home"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Home"
            android:id="@+id/textView_Home"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Account"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/iconhome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_Account"
            android:scaleType="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="My Account"
            android:id="@+id/textView_Account"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Scan"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/iconhome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_Scan"
            android:scaleType="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Scan policy"
            android:id="@+id/textView_Scan"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_IDCheck"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/iconhome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_IDCheck"
            android:scaleType="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="ID Check"
            android:id="@+id/textView_IDCheck"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#ffffffff">
    <include
        layout="@layout/IncludeLogoTitle" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="25px">
        <Button
            android:text="Scan a policy"
            android:background="@drawable/lark_btn2_xhdpi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnScanPolicy"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:maxHeight="21dp"
            android:minHeight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="Perform an ID Check"
            android:background="@drawable/lark_btn2_xhdpi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnPerformIdCheck"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:maxHeight="21dp"
            android:minHeight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="You have 0 ID credits remaining"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtCreditsremaining"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <Button
            android:text="Top up online"
            android:background="@drawable/lark_btn2_xhdpi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTopUp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:maxHeight="21dp"
            android:minHeight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/IncludePartOfLark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your layout XML

Comment: Added the actionbar xaml, fragment layout and theme.xml

Comment: You should use NoActionBar theme to remove that

Comment: Will that not remove the Action bar tabs ?

Comment: Tried it anyway in my theme.xml, doesn't remove the black bar indicated.

Comment: Normally when you use layout_weight you should set the corresponding height or width attribute to 0dp, as you've mostly done here...except one place.  The second LinearLayout in your fragment specifies layout_weight of 100 but also layout_height as 'wrap_content' might be worth setting this to 0dp. I'm not sure if this is the cause but I've seen similar things cause strange results

Comment: Hi Lewis. That didn't get rid of my black bar but have kept the code change as you described. ITs beginning to look like I am going to have to rewrite this layout from scratch, bit by bit until I see what is causing that black bar to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On setting up my action bar I was using the following calls in the main activities onCreate

```
ActionBar.SetCustomView (Resource.Layout.action_bar);
ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled (true);
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled (false);
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
```

The culprit was the `ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs` call. Changed code to the following and now all is good.

```
ActionBar.SetCustomView (Resource.Layout.action_bar);
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled (true);
```